# How to use HTTP (not HTTPS) with RequestBin

Tags: http, request

I would like to use the [RequestBin](https://requestb.in) tool for HTTP (not HTTPS) debugging. However, it seems that it doesn't support it, e.g:

```
$ curl http://requestb.in/1eqnllm1 -vvvv
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 104.31.87.204...
* Connected to requestb.in (104.31.87.204) port 80 (#0)
> GET /1eqnllm1 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: requestb.in
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Tue, 23 May 2017 09:56:28 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=ddf08bf899d8bb92e06630f02f37f0f471495533388; expires=Wed, 23-May-18 09:56:28 GMT; path=/; domain=.requestb.in; HttpOnly
< Cache-Control: max-age=3600
< Expires: Tue, 23 May 2017 10:56:28 GMT
< Location: https://requestb.in/1eqnllm1
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
* Server cloudflare-nginx is not blacklisted
< Server: cloudflare-nginx
< CF-RAY: 3637253d814f0de1-MAD
< 
* Connection #0 to host requestb.in left intact
```

I want to get a `200 OK` not a `302 Moved Permanently`

Is there any way of configuring RequestBin to work that way, please? I have looked arround the web page, but I haven't find anything...

RequestBin alternative able to work with HTTP are also welcome.

Comment: Side-node: not sure if something has changed recently in RequestBin, but I'd say that last week it supported HTTP based on some dirty test I did (unfortunatelly I didn't "recorded" that testing session).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just hit this too. Says on twitter they've moved to https only. 
https://twitter.com/johnsheehan/status/865646082654584832

Going to try this -> http://putsreq.com/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll try putsreq.com. Looks nice

Comment: It seems PutsReq also stop working in HTTP. The `http://putsreq.com` URL redirects to `https://putsreq.com` :(

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://www.mocky.io for http response as putsreq.com doesn't support http anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://requestbin.net/

It is similar to requestb.in and supports http.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.