# http-only site to test REST requests?

Tags: rest, http, testing, https, raku

After the latest move by [httpbin](https://httpbin.com) to HTTPS, apparently all sites that accepted test REST requests have disappeared. I've checked [all mentioned in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44131638/how-to-use-http-not-https-with-requestbin), and either they do not allow all kind of requests, or have also moved to HTTPS. For [Raku modules such as this one, LWP::Simple](https://github.com/perl6/perl6-lwp-simple), we need a HTTP-only site due to problems with certain operating systems. So is there any site left or will we have to roll out our own server?

Comment: Feels to me that for testing, you would need to roll out a server anyway, as you want to be able to run the test in a firewalled environment.  And running an HTTP server in Perl 6 is not that difficult nowadays?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use http://eu.httpbin.org. This URL doesn't redirect http to https.

Answer (score 11):

http://www.neverssl.com/ and http://neverssl.com/ are another good options. They will never use HTTPS/SSL.